# htaccess and deeplinking back button

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, deep-linking

I am implementing the following htaccess to deep link into an ajax heavy site,

It works fine except if you link into the site from outside you need to hit the back button twice quickly to go back.

Has anyone tackled this before successfully and if so how ?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrite rules to support deeplinking
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /studio/$1/ [NC,R]
RewriteRule ^studio/families/([^/]*)/?$ /studio/inc-discover-static/$1 [NC,NE,R]
RewriteRule ^studio/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php#!section=$1 [NC,NE,R]
RewriteRule ^studio/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php#!section=$1&sub=$2 [NC,NE,R,L]      
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Just realized after answering that when you are talking about deeplinking, you might be referring to a reason for using the R flag, but I'm not entirely sure what you mean with that part. So: Are you intentionally using the R-flag?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `[R]` flag (which stands for Redirect) on your RewriteRules, which means that the redirect is made visible to the browser. If you remove it, all of this will happen only on the server and the user won't notice any of it, as such you won't have to press back twice.